# Division algorithm proof intuitive

Tags: recursive-algorithms

The following algorithm can be used for division. Can someone intuitively explain or offer proof that quotient returned from recursive call (say `q'`) is such that quotient that should be returned from current function call (say `q`) is at max one less than  `2q'`. I get the pattern but don't understand it well enough.

```
divide(x,y):
  if (y>x) return 0
  q = divide (x, 2*y)
  if ((x-2*q*y)<y)
    return 2*q
  else
    return 2*q+1
```

Comment: This algorithm is effectively doing long division in base $2$. (The way we were first taught to do division back in elementary school - at least in ye olden days, except in base $2$ instead of base $10$.)

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm is doing long division in base $2$. For example:
$$34 = 10\,0010_b\\6=110_b$$
Doing long division:
$$\require{enclose}\begin{array}{r}
101\\[-3pt]
110 \enclose{longdiv}{100010}\\[-3pt]
-\underline{110\phantom{00}}\\[-3pt]
01010\\[-3pt]
-\underline{000\phantom{0}}\\[-3pt]
1010\\[-3pt]
-\underline{110}\\[-3pt]
100
\end{array}$$
giving a quotient of $101_b = 5$ and a remainder of $100_b = 4$.

The algorithm starts by moving the divisor $y$ to the left (by doubling it) until the result of subtracting from $x$ gives a result less than the moved $y$ (actually it goes one move further, but returns $0$ for that level, effectvely making the previous call the first one of consequence). This gives
$$\begin{array}{r}
1\\[-3pt]
110 \enclose{longdiv}{100010}\\[-3pt]
-\underline{110\phantom{00}}\\[-3pt]
01010
\end{array}$$
with $q = 1$ being the value on top.
at the next level down, $q$ is multiplied by $2$, moving one place left. So now the remainder is $x - (2q)y$. If this is big enough that we can subtract out one more $y$, then we add a $1$ to the quotient as well. In the example, it wasn't big enough, so we end up with that bit being $0$:
$$\begin{array}{r}
10\\[-3pt]
110 \enclose{longdiv}{100010}\\[-3pt]
-\underline{110\phantom{00}}\\[-3pt]
01010\\[-3pt]
-\underline{000\phantom{0}}\\[-3pt]
1010
\end{array}$$
At the next level, we multiply $q$ by $2$ again. Notice that $x - (2q)y$ is big enough that we can subtract out one more $y$, so we end up adding $1$ to $2q$ to account for it.

And then we discover we are at the bottom. The remainder is below the original divisor $y$ and the process stops.

Comment: 1. This algorithm is certainly adapted to binary numbers based on long division of decimal numbers BUT this algorithm also works for decimal numbers. 2. I understand what this algorithm does but I don't understand why in cases when ```x -2qy > y```, we can only add 1 more to it (```2q+1```) and not anything more such as ```2q+2``` or ```2q+3```, etc. I don't understand the true nature of underlying constraint.

Comment: 1. Of course it works for "decimal numbers". There is no such thing as "decimal numbers vs binary numbers". They are just numbers. "Decimal" vs "binary" are just two slightly different means we can use to express the numbers. But the numbers themselves are the same however they are expressed. When you express them in binary and follow the steps in long division, you get this algorithm.

Comment: 2. The process of integer long division base $n$ is this: when dividing the dividend $p$ by the divisor $d$, find the integer $k$ such that $dn^k \le p < dn^{k+1}$. Then find the integer $q$ such that $dqn^k \le p < d(q+1)n^k$. By the pick of $k$, it must be that $1 \le q <n$. The remainder $r = p - dqn^k$ satisfies $0 \le r < dn^k$, Then to find the remaining digits, One repeats the process with $r$ as the new value of $p$, except that instead of finding a new $k$ as above, one just decreases the previous $k$ by $1$ each time, which allows $q = 0$ as a possibility.

Comment: When $n = 2$ as here, $q$ can only be $0$ or $1$. After the initial identification of $k$, at every step the dividend (remainder of the previous step) is always $<dn^{k+1}$, so $q$ cannot be greater than $n-1$. When $n = 2, q$ is either $0$ or $1$. If it were somehow higher, that means you failed to properly execute some previous step of the process.

Comment: "By the pick of , it must be that `1≤<`" Lets say I deliberately pick `n = 2` for numbers that are represented using base 10, algorithm base case is still going to return either q = 0 or 1 as algorithm keeps calling itself until k is such that `*^≤<*^(+1)`. Just like you explained. Once you get the quotient retuned from base case (call it q'), now quotient from current call (call it q) is not within bounds`1≤<` but rather `1*n≤<^2` ?? we account for this bound increase by doing `q = n*q'` but there is this extra plus 1 that comes up, that is what I don't understand

Comment: There is no "bound" increase. It is the same algorithm I described. $q' = q$. The only difference between writing the number in base $n$ vs base $10$ while using that algorithm is that the base-$n$ expression for $dn^k$ is just the base-$n$ expression for $d$ shifted to the left by $k$ digits. If you are working in a different base than $n$, it is harder to calculate the expression for $dn^k$. Thus working in base $n$ is highly advantageous for doing the calculation by hand. But the base you work in does not somehow change how the algorithm I described functions.